# "Read more" link in short description in product page

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute

I used below code to limit the short description in product page:

1) it truncates all other attributes with text field in product page not only `if ($_product->getData('short_description'))`. How make the if to check if this attribute is `short_description` then do the task?

2) what should be in `<a href="#">Read More</a>` that after clicking on read more it expands the text?

```
<div class="value" <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeAddAttribute;?>>
        <?php  if ($_product->getData('short_description')) {
            $string = strip_tags($_product->getData('short_description'));

            if (strlen($string) > 50) {
                // truncate string
                $stringCut = substr($string, 0, 50);
                $string = substr($stringCut, 0, strrpos($stringCut, ' ')).'... <a href="#">Read More</a>';
            }
            echo $string;
        }else {?>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeValue; }?>

    </div>
```

Comment: If u want on same Page, then you have other div with Full Description. Once it clicked "Read More" you have to show that Div & hide Your Current One

Comment: Is there Other div for short description! Where? Yes I want short description with read more link in product page

Comment: You have to do it via Custom Code

Comment: simply you can achieve this using jquery.

Comment: @shyam: php is the requirement :/

Comment: @ankit, I'll try it and keep here updated. Tnx

Comment: But i wont suggest @ankits solution. Two description in same page might make the page load even slower. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: I also agree @ShyamKrishnaSreekumar So what will be Effective Solution?

Comment: First i will suggest using js as we can do animation in it while toggle.
Another option is to use css. See :https://codepen.io/Idered/pen/AeBgF

Comment: @ShyamKrishnaSreekumar, the problem is that it's hard for my client dealing with product page in admin panel put the short description in html tags. This is the reason it must be done via php.

Comment: @AnkitShah, I made it based on your hint. Just the first question is not yet pointed out ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it like below : php + jQuery ;)

```
<?php  if ($_code =="short_description") {
            $decsriptionstr = $_product->getData('short_description');
            $string = strip_tags($decsriptionstr );

            if (strlen($string) > 50) {

                // truncate string
                $stringCut = substr($string, 0, 50);
                $string = substr($stringCut, 0, strrpos($stringCut, ' '));
            }?> <span class="teaser"> <?php   echo $string; ?> </span>
            <span  class="completeDescription"><?php echo $decsriptionstr; ?> </span>
            <span class="moreLink">more...</span>
            <?php

        }
```

And jQuery part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".moreLink").toggle(function () {
                        $(this).text("less..").siblings(".completeDescription").show();
                    }, function () {
                        $(this).text("more..").siblings(".completeDescription").hide();
                    });
</script>
```

**And css**:

```
.completeDescription{
  display:none;
}

.moreLink{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: add jquery part in answer.

Comment: You can do also above way.

Comment: @zinat, you can add js to complete answer.

Comment: @Rakesh, It's there now ;)

Comment: @GopalPatel, here you go ;)

Answer (score 6):

You have to just overrider **`attribute.phtml`** file from **module-catalog** core module.

Copy file inside your theme,

**`app/design/frontend/Vendor/luma/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/attribute.phtml`**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * Product view template
 *
 * @see \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description
 */
?>
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$_call = $block->getAtCall();
$_code = $block->getAtCode();
$_className = $block->getCssClass();
$_attributeLabel = $block->getAtLabel();
$_attributeType = $block->getAtType();
$_attributeAddAttribute = $block->getAddAttribute();

if ($_attributeLabel && $_attributeLabel == 'default') {
    $_attributeLabel = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getFrontendLabel();
}
if ($_attributeType && $_attributeType == 'text') {
    $_attributeValue = ($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->$_call(), $_code)) ? $_product->getAttributeText($_code) : '';
} else {
    $_attributeValue = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->$_call(), $_code);
}
?>



<?php if ($_attributeValue): ?>
    <?php if($_code === 'short_description') { ?>
        <div class="value more" <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeAddAttribute;?> >
        <?php  if ($_product->getData('short_description')) {
            $string = strip_tags($_product->getData('description'));

            if (strlen($string) > 50) {
                // truncate string
                $stringCut = substr($string, 0, 50);
                $string = substr($stringCut, 0, strrpos($stringCut, ' ')).'... <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="readmore">Read More</a>';
            }
            echo $string;
            ?>
        <?php
        }else {?>
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeValue; 
            }
        ?>
        </div>

        <div class="less" style="display:none">
            <?php echo $_attributeValue; ?>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="readless">Read Less</a>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            console.log('test');
            require(["jquery"],function($){
                $('.readmore').on("click",function(){
                    $('.less').show();
                    $('.more').hide();
                });
                $('.readless').on("click",function(){
                    $('.less').hide();
                    $('.more').show();
                });
            });
        </script>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <div class="product attribute <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_className?>">
            <?php if ($_attributeLabel != 'none'): ?><strong class="type"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeLabel?></strong><?php endif; ?>
            <div class="value" <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeAddAttribute;?>><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeValue; ?></div>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Read more link for short description in  product page.**

You have to just override **`attribute.phtml`** file from **module-catalog** core module.

Copy file inside your theme,

**`app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/attribute.phtml`**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * Product view template
 *
 * @see \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description
 */
?>
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$_call = $block->getAtCall();
$_code = $block->getAtCode();
$_className = $block->getCssClass();
$_attributeLabel = $block->getAtLabel();
$_attributeType = $block->getAtType();
$_attributeAddAttribute = $block->getAddAttribute();

if ($_attributeLabel && $_attributeLabel == 'default') {
    $_attributeLabel = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getFrontendLabel();
}
if ($_attributeType && $_attributeType == 'text') {
    $_attributeValue = ($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->$_call(), $_code)) ? $_product->getAttributeText($_code) : '';
} else {
    $_attributeValue = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->$_call(), $_code);
}
?>



<?php if ($_attributeValue): ?>
    <?php if($_code === 'short_description') { ?>
        <div class="value more" <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeAddAttribute;?> >
        <?php  if ($_product->getData('short_description')) {
            $string = strip_tags($_product->getData('description'));

            if (strlen($string) > 50) {
                // truncate string
                $stringCut = substr($string, 0, 50);
                $string = substr($stringCut, 0, strrpos($stringCut, ' ')).'... <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="readmore">Read More</a>';
            }
            echo $string;
            ?>
        <?php
        }else {?>
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeValue; 
            }
        ?>
        </div>

        <div class="less" style="display:none">
            <?php echo $_attributeValue; ?>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="readless">Read Less</a>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            console.log('test');
            require(["jquery"],function($){
                $('.readmore').on("click",function(){
                    $('.less').show();
                    $('.more').hide();
                });
                $('.readless').on("click",function(){
                    $('.less').hide();
                    $('.more').show();
                });
            });
        </script>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <div class="product attribute <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_className?>">
            <?php if ($_attributeLabel != 'none'): ?><strong class="type"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeLabel?></strong><?php endif; ?>
            <div class="value" <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeAddAttribute;?>><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeValue; ?></div>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

actually I have the same issue and also I use a third-party theme
when I added attribute-phtml on this root for me;(public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product) that I got this error message
[image: /public_html/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Process/Queue.php(248): Magento\Deploy\Process\Queue->executePackage(Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\Package),] 'frontend/Local/...', Array, false)
Anotherly I have magento_catalog on my theme root directory with xml files as I attached their screenshot