# I've to limit the blog section from showing the whole description on homepage, how can i add a read more section in blog

Tags: blog

I've to limit the blog section from showing the whole description on homepage, how can i add a read more section in blog, i've used magefan blog extension, also please suggest in which file do i've to make changes.

Comment: Please check on this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/142879/84221

Comment: Please provide full information like which extension are you used for blog functionality.